# sqlplus print running statement

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is there a way where sqlplus can print what statement it executed.
I mean I have some .sql files that I run in a bash script. I need to know when I read the log file which statement sqlplus ran.

Example:
Say I have this test.sql file:

```
set timing on
create table foo (a varchar2(10));
create table bar (b varchar2(10));
exit
```

When I check the log I get this:

```
Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Which is not informative. Is there a way where I can get output like this:

```
Table foo created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02

Table bar created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Or even like this:

```
create table foo (a varchar2(10));

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02

create table bar (b varchar2(10));

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

I know I can use PROMPT before each statement but I have big sql scripts and it would be tedious to write PROMPT before each statement.

**EDIT:**

For Allan's solution to always work (i.e. using "**set echo on**"), you should avoid the following:

1) Don't use the -S option with sqlplus because this will suppress the display of echoing of commands.

2) Don't "cat" your script to sqlplus like this:

```
cat test.sql | sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `SET ECHO ON`, which will repeat the each statement that is issued.

Comment: Thanks. This worked by avoiding two things. See my updated question.

Comment: This doesn't work when running `@script.sql`.  In that case, the commands within the script get echoed, but the original command (`@script.sql`) doesn't get echoed.  For tracability purposes, I really need the user commands to be logged.

Comment: (in all other cases though, `set echo on` works great)

Comment: This still isn't working with my here document. Is that problematic like `cat`?

Answer (score -3):

If you need to know the exact creation time for the objects you could query DBA_OBJECTS or ALL_OBJECTS for the CREATED column.